# Possible to download packaged deb file before final publishing on myapps portal?

Tags: software-center, application-development

first of all sorry if this is a stupid question (or the wrong place to ask said stupid question!), but I've looked all over for an answer and couldn't find one.

I've recently submitted my game through Ubuntu's myapps portal. They kindly packaged it all up, approved it, and it's now down to me to click the publish button. Before I do that though, I'd really like to download their packaged up deb file and test it myself. It's not that I doubt Ubuntu's QA, it's just I know *exactly* how it should look and behave, and just want to double check everythings OK before publishing. Unfortunately though I've clicked all over the myapps portal and cannot find any place to download it.

In the technical details it says it's in a private PPA on launchpad, but when I logged into the launchpad site with my myapps portal login details, it didn't seem to be there either. Will it show up there to download after I publish it?

Can anyone shed any light on this? Or point me to a more appropriate place to ask the question? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest Way is to actually publish the app change the price to 0.00 install it if there are issue you can immediately send it back to it's current ready to publish state basically clicking on the unpublish button.

Don't forget to change the price back.